# Problemas con 3 arrasy A, B Y C

Tags: java, array

La cosa está así:

Poseo un `array A[n]`, con longitud variable, ingresada por el usuario, el cual luego, es llenada posición por posición con un valor que también ingresa el usuario.

Ahora, lo que hice, es que los números pares que se encuentren dentro del `array A[n]`, se guardaran el otro `array B[contpares]`, el cual también posee una longitud variable, que se le asigna contando el numero de términos pares existente en el `array A[n]`, para luego asignar dichos valores pares en el `array B`, teniendo un `array` de solo números pares provenientes de A.
También hice lo anteriormente descrito para números impares, y los guarde en el `array C[continpares]`.

Mi problema se sitúa a la hora de desplegar los resultados:
Sí al `array A[n]`, se asigno la longitud, y luego la lleno con valores solo pares, me despliega correctamente el `array B`, con los términos pares del `array A`, y haciendo lo mismo con valores impares, también tengo un despliegue correcto, pero todo **cambia** cuando alterno valores pares e impares en el `Array A`, ya que me marca error al desplegar dichos valores, y yo lo que busco es desplegar los 2 vectores `B(pares de A) y C(inpares de A)`, al mismo tiempo, de esta manera:

suponiendo que A quede así:

```
A={1,2,3,4}

array B 

2,4 

array c

1,3
```

dejo el código, aquí:

```
     int val=0;
     BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(System.in));
     int A[];
     int B[];
     int C[];
     int contpar=0;
     int continpar=0;
     int longv=0;
     int temp1=0;
     int temp2=0;
     System.out.println("ingrese la longitud del vector A");
     longv=Integer.parse.Int(br.readLine());
    for(int i=0; i<longv; i++)
    {
    System.out.println("Ingrese valor para el vector A con posicion ["+(i+1)+"]");
    val=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    A[i]=val;
    }
    for(int j=0; j<longv; j++)
    {
       if(A[j]%2==0)
      {
       contpar++;
      }
       if(A[j]%3==0)
      {
       continpar++;
      }

    }
    B=new int [contpar];
    C=new int[continpar];
    for(int k=0; i<longv; k++)
    {
     if(A[K]%2==0)
      {
        temp1= A[k];
        B[k]=temp1;
      }
     else
      {
        temp2= A[k];
        C[k]=temp2;
      }
     }

      for(int i=0; i<contpar; i++)
      {
        System.out.print(B[i]);
      }
      for(int j=0; j<continpar; j++);
      {
        System.out.print(C[j]);
      }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Sí ingreso la siguiere sucesión, 1, 2,3,4

Comment: Me da un error, y me marca el valor 2  en rojo

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir el `error` completo?

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente lo que te pasa es que cuando recorres A para ir asignado los valores a los otros 2 arrays, intentas meter los valoeres en las mismas posiciones de B y C que en la posición que lo has leido de A, y por tanto generas un ArrayIndexOutofBounds.

Se arregla llevando un indice de los arrays B y C aparte para saber por donde tienes que ir metiéndoselos.

Te he arreglado un poco el código (pero intentando respetarte la mayor parte) y quedaría así:

```
        int val=0;
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new
         InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int A[];
        int B[];
        int C[];
        int contpar=0;
        int continpar=0;
        int longv=0;
        int temp1=0;
        int temp2=0;
        System.out.println("ingrese la longitud del vector A");
        longv=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        A = new int[longv];
        for(int i=0; i<longv; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Ingrese valor para el vector A con posicion ["+(i+1)+"]");
            val=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            A[i]=val;
        }
        for(int j=0; j<longv; j++)
        {
            if(A[j]%2==0)
            {
                contpar++;
            }else{
                continpar++;
            }

        }
        B=new int [contpar];
        C=new int[continpar];
        int indexB = 0;
        int indexC = 0;
        for(int k=0; k<longv; k++)
        {
            if(A[k]%2==0)
            {
                temp1= A[k];
                B[indexB]=temp1;
                indexB++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp2= A[k];
                C[indexC]=temp2;
                indexC++;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<contpar; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(B[i]);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<continpar; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(C[j]);
        }
```

Luego por otro lado en la condición que usas para contar los pares e impares simplemente he puesto un else a la condición de par (sino es par es que es impar) ya que tenías puesto un %3 que tampoco es correcto por que por ejemplo el 6 cumple esa condición y esta claro que no es impar.